# Why a recursion happens here?

Tags: python, class, recursion, decorator

Recently I read [an interesting discussion on how to make a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python).
One of the solutions was a [tricky decorator defining a class inside its code as a substitute for decorated class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810621/862380):

```
def singleton(class_):
    class class_w(class_):
        _instance = None
        def __new__(class2, *args, **kwargs):
            if class_w._instance is None:
                class_w._instance = super(class_w, class2).__new__(class2, *args, **kwargs)
                class_w._instance._sealed = False
            return class_w._instance
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self._sealed:
                return
            super(class_w, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._sealed = True
    class_w.__name__ = class_.__name__
    return class_w

@singleton
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        print text
    @classmethod
    def name(class_):
        print class_.__name__

x = MyClass(111)
x.name()
y = MyClass(222)
print id(x) == id(y)
```

Output is:

```
111     # the __init__ is called only on the 1st time
MyClass # the __name__ is preserved
True    # this is actually the same instance
```

It is stated, that if we use `super(MyClass, self).__init__(text)` inside `__init__` of `MyClass`, we get into **recursion**.

I tested and indeed the recursion happens.
But, as I understand, `MyClass` inherits `object`, so `super(MyClass, self)` should just merely be `object`, but it turns out that `super(MyClass, self)` is `__main__.MyClass`

Could you explain what happens here step by step for me to understand the reasons why the recursion happens?

Comment: Super() is a bit tricky with python, check http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that by writing `super(MyClass, self).__init__(text)`, you are saying to use the super relative to whatever class `MyClass` refers to at the time `super` is called.  But the decorator replaces `MyClass` with a subclass of itself.  So when your original `__init__` method is called `MyClass` actually refers to a subclass of the class which defines the executing method.

To say it step by step, I'm going to call the original class (as written in the source) `OrigMyClass`, and the resulting version (after the decorator) `DecMyClass`.  I'll use `MyClass` just as a variable, because its meaning changes during the course of execution.

1. You define an `__init__` method on `OrigMyClass`, but that `__init__` method calls `super(MyClass, self)`, not `super(OrigMyClass, self)`.  Thus, what method will actually be called depends on what `MyClass` refers to *at the time the method is called*. The value of `MyClass` is looked up at execution time like any other variable; placing it inside the `super` call or inside the `__init__` method does not magically bind it to the class it happens to be in when you write it; variables in functions are evaluated when they are called, not when they are defined.
2. The decorator runs.  The decorator defines a new class `DecMyClass` as a subclass of `OrigMyClass`.  `DecMyClass` defines an `__init__` that calls `super(DecMyClass, self)`.
3. After the decorator runs, the name `MyClass` is bound to the class `DecMyClass`.  Note that this means that when the `super(MyClass, self)` call later executes, it will be doing `super(DecMyClass, self)`.
4. When you do `MyClass(111)`, you instantiate an object of `DecMyClass`.  `DecMyClass.__init__` calls `super(DecMyClass, self).__init__`.  This executes `OrigMyClass.__init__`.
5. `OrigMyClass.__init__` calls `super(MyClass, self).__init__`.  Because `MyClass` refers to `DecMyClass`, this is the same as `super(DecMyClass, self).__init__`.  But `DecMyClass` is a subclass of `OrigMyClass`.  The key point is that because `MyClass` refers to `DecMyClass`, `OrigMyClass` is actually calling super *on a subclass of itself*.
6. Thus `super(DecMyClass, self).__init__` again calls `OrigMyClass.__init__`, which again calls itself, and so on to infinity.

The effect is the same as this code, which may make the execution path more obvious:

```
>>> class Super(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "In super init"
...         super(Sub, self).__init__()
>>> class Sub(Super):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "In sub init"
...         super(Sub, self).__init__()
```

Note that `Super` calls `super(Sub, self)`.  It is trying to call a superclass method, but it tries to call the superclass method of `Sub`.  The superclass of `Sub` is `Super`, so `Super` winds up calling its own method again.

Edit: Just to clarify the name-lookup issues you raised, here's another slightly different example that has the same result:

```
>>> class Super(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "In super init"
...         super(someClass, self).__init__()
>>> class Sub(Super):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "In sub init"
...         super(Sub, self).__init__()
>>> someClass = Sub
```

This should make it clear that the class argument to `super` (the first argument, here `someClass`) is not special in any way.  It is just an ordinary name whose value is looked up in the ordinary way at the ordinary time, namely when the `super` call is executed.  As shown by this example, the variable doesn't even have to exist at the time you define the method; the value is looked up at the time you *call* the method.

Comment: Oh. It was difficult to understand. But it seems to me that I got it! The key thing that I didn't understand was that why `super(MyClass, self)` is not always referring to `OrigMyClass`, but at some point (after decoration works) starts to refer to `DecMyClass`. And eventually I got that `__init__` just looks up the lixical scopes until it finds `MyClass` in module's scope, where it refers to `DecMyClass`. Before that understanding I thought that `__init__` lives inside `MyClass`, so it should be always bound to initial class `OrigMyClass`. Now everything is clear! Thank you!

Comment: @ovgolovin: Yes, but it's worth nothing that this is the same thing that *always* happens.  Any reference to any name in any function is always looked up in this way (unless the name is being assigned to).  It's not anything specific to `super`.

Comment: @ovgolovin: I added another little example to clarify this.